# XSLT: Set namespace as first attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, powershell, namespaces, transformation

I have a problem with namespace position in result xml file after xsl transformation.

My transformation stylesheet looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:element name="SmartDriveUpdates">
  <xsl:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation">
    <xsl:text>LightSpeedXMLSchema.xsd</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
...
</xsl:element>
```

In output xml file I want to get root node as

```
<SmartDriveUpdates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="LightSpeedXMLSchema.xsd">
```

But instead I have

```
<SmartDriveUpdates xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="LightSpeedXMLSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

I also tried to precode root node in xsl stylesheet as

```
<SmartDriveUpdates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="LightSpeedXMLSchema.xsd">
  ...
</SmartDriveUpdates>
```

But I get the same wrong result.

Transformation aplied to xml file by using Transform method from system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform .NET class. I use PowerShell for this purpose:

```
Function Convert-WithXslt($originalXmlFilePath, $xslFilePath, $outputFilePath) {
## Simplistic error handling
$xslFilePath = Resolve-Path $xslFilePath
If( -not (Test-Path $xslFilePath) ) { 
    Throw "Can't find the XSL file" 
} 

$originalXmlFilePath = Resolve-Path $originalXmlFilePath
If( -not (Test-Path $originalXmlFilePath) ) { 
    Throw "Can't find the XML file" 
}

#$outputFilePath = Resolve-Path $outputFilePath
If( -not (Test-Path (Split-Path $originalXmlFilePath)) ) {
    Throw "Can't find the output folder" 
} 

## Get an XSL Transform object (try for the new .Net 3.5 version first)
$EAP = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

$script:xslt = New-Object system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform
Trap [System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException] 
{  # no 3.5, use the slower 2.0 one
    $ErrorActionPreference = $EAP
    $script:xslt = New-Object system.xml.xsl.xsltransform
}
$ErrorActionPreference = $EAP

## load xslt file
$xslt.load( $xslFilePath )

## transform 
$xslt.Transform( $originalXmlFilePath, $outputFilePath )
}
```

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The order of namespace definitions and attributes is implementation dependent**.

You have two choices:

1. Use another XSLT processor -- Saxon 6.5.4 or Saxon 9.x (there is a .NET version), some versions of Altova (XML-SPY) and XQSharp all generate the output as desired.
2. Continue using XslCompiledTransform, but implement your own XmlWriter object. You have the freedom in the implementation of the WriteElementString Method() to produce the element's serialization in any way desired.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use own XmlWriter or fix our Merge Tool.

Answer (score 2):

The order of attributes and of namespace declarations attributes does not matter and I don't think you can define that order when you use XSLT. Why does the order matter to you?

Comment: I know that, but we have some Merge Tool that merge those files after transformation and it crashes if don't find namespace as first node :(

Comment: If you have something relying on the attribute order, it is broken and you should fix that if you have any control of it.

Comment: Agreed. Any tool that relies on attributes being in a particular order should be sent back to its maker with a demand for a refund. Describing the XML as wrong, rather than the tool that's consuming it, is the wrong mentality.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to abandon XslCompiledTransform, you can use XQSharp's XmlWriter implementations rather than writing your own, which may produce the result you are looking for,